# Раскрывающийся полностью текст html

Tags: html, javascript, css

У меня есть текст, который изначально видно не полностью, нужно чтоб при нажатии кнопки "показать полностью" был виден весь текст и наоборот.

Типо так:

```
текст текст текст текст
текст текст текст текст

текст текст текст текст
текст текст текст текст
```

Показать полностью и после:

```
текст текст текст текст
текст текст текст текст

текст текст текст текст
текст текст текст текст
```

Остальной текст скрыть

Comment: @skies, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Вариантов масса, посмотрите в сторону Jquery Slide Toggle (http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_slidetoggle.asp ).

А для самых занимательных есть вариант на чистом CSS без скриптов: http://jsfiddle.net/o3na69ar/1/

Answer (score 1):

Можно, в принципе, написать самому, если определиться с логикой работы скрипта, это не очень сложно.

А если знаний в JS недостаточно и просто неохота писать велосипед, который сделали до вас, можно использовать какой-нибудь плагин, например, [jQuery Collapser](http://plugins.jquery.com/collapser/). Посмотреть демо работы этого плагина с различными условиями для обрезания текста можно [вот тут](http://www.aakashweb.com/demos/jquery-collapser/) .